# Visual Studios .NET 4 - adding Oracle Database as Data Source - Warnings about OracleDataAdatper deprecated

Tags: oracle, visual-studio, datasource

When I add an Oracle Database as a Data Source to my project, the automatically generated code in the TableAdapter section is uses System.Data.OracleDataAdapter which is obsolete.

Following the documentation explains that you should use the third party Oracle software (ODAC). Given that the code is autogenerated, I am confused.

Am I missing something here?

**Possible Solutions:**

1. I could use .NET 3.5 for my Data Access Layer
2. Ignore the warnings
3. Manually Create Table Adapters
4. Something I am missing?

Comment: Why isn't "use the third party Oracle software (ODAC)" one of your possible solutions?

Comment: I guess I am unsure how to add a datasource using ODAC.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studios. Add the Data Source in the same way as before (except the form now looks different as a result of the newly installed add on).